# PHP JAVA bridge class not found complete steps if anyone know as path error

Tags: java, php, classnotfound

Well, my question is so simple I have one class file called apples.class and I also have apples.jar file.

Now apples.class file I put inside C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\classes\apples.class

Second apples.jar file I put inside C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\lib\apples.jar

Now, I am trying to create object of apples.class file but I am getting error of

```
java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new apples. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apples
```

And my code is:

```
require_once("java/Java.inc");

        exec("java apples", $output);
        print_r($output);//working so my javaphp bridge is fine 

     $myobj = new java("apples"); //not creating object and return me above error
```

So if someone please help me out by letting me know what I am missing and how I can create object of apples class. And My second main question is I put files in correct place why still I get the error.

Note: question I haven't found anywhere and wherever I found it's not perfect steps so highly appreciate if someone can provide step by step and please don't make it this question as similar to any other question as it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Class names are case sensitive. You need a capital J in Java ...

```
$myobj = new Java("apples");
```

You might have to include the package in the call as well, eg;

```
$myobj = new Java("com.fruit.apples");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I made Java capital as you said and not making any difference and can you also suggest me alternative please. and one more question my above paths fine or do I have to specify them thanks a lot my friend so far....

Comment: Hi I am new to java can you tell me how I can do alternative like do I have to write java_autoload() or what and if java_autoload() then do I have to provide path?

Comment: Is `apples` in a package?

Comment: Take a look at the source for `apples`. The first line should tell you which package it's in. It looks something like this, `package com.fruit;`. You need to specify where the class is in your PHP call, see my edited answer.

Comment: ok my Firstapple.java file have following code                                 package com.fruits;

class apples{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  System.out.println("hello apple");
 }
}

Comment: and my php side code is  $myobj = new Java("com.fruits.apples");  not working:( please do something as almost spend 4 hours on it

Comment: The filename needs to be the same as the class name in java. This is a requirement. Don't call it `Firstapple.java`, call it `apples.java` compile the code and put the resulting `.jar` file in your `/lib` folder.